# Can VS Code display modified files by folder in git version manager?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

look at the screenshot:

[image: modified files in git]

vscode lists all modified files, and shows which folder the file belongs to, but it is not clear enough, I want modified files to be displayed by folder， just like in file tree. is it possible?

Comment: Tree functionality:  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51476096/visual-studio-code-group-pending-changes-by-folder/58274085#58274085  You can display your source control files like a tree - that is, by folder - since v1.43.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, yet.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/40712) which asks a few improvements for the Git tab, and one of the comments asks for "Sort by folder".

You should *upvote* on that issue, making it more visible to the VS Code team.

Comment: The linked issue #40712 is marked as solved in PR #99768 in June 2020, which locked the issue; upvotes aren't possible anymore.

Comment: Yes, which is good, since my answer was made in 2018. The @VonC answer, made in 2020 has more details about the "next steps", after the issue being solved.

Answer (score 3):

It appears the [issue 40712 "SCM: Support sort"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/40712) ([mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49567808/6309) by [alefragnani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7758872/alefragnani)) might finally (for VSCode 1.47, June 2020) be resolved.

See [PR 99768 "View/Sort feature for SCM viewlet"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/99768), which proposes:

- a sort by status
- a sort by path

See [View sort](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/4762c7285c385d1ebd5076b5414a7874117c48aa/release-notes/v1_47.md#view-and-sort):

> ### View and Sort

> We have added support for sorting your changes in the source control view by name, path (default), and state when using the list view option.
> We have consolidated the view options (list vs. tree) and sort options into a new View & Sort menu item in the context menu.

[image: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/raw/vnext/release-notes/images/1_47/scm-view&sort.png]

---

And with VSCode 1.64 (Jan. 2022), this sort order will be persistent.

See [issue 120271](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/120271) / [PR 123232](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/123232) and [commit 9152469](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/915246964f8d9c2c30f3e2a0562effa84b6b49c6)

- Add scm view default sort setting.
- Add scm view sort to workspace storage.

The options are:

- Sort the repository changes by path
- Sort the repository changes by file name
- Sort the repository changes by SCM status

Comment: I don't have access to that menu in VS Code 1.75

Comment: @Myer I do, in VSCode 1.75.1. Are you in the "Source Control" view?

Comment: I am able to see it now! I was in the source control view before, but I had to look up above the workspace panel toolbar to the source control panel toolbar @VonC

Comment: @Myer OK, I am glad you found it. This menu is not very intuitive.