# Visual Studio Code - Group pending changes by folder

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-code

I want to get rid of my current IDE (Jetbrains) and migrate to Visual Studio Code because of some supported extensions.

There is only one thing I'm missing in VS Code...

If I have multiple files in source control as pending changes, they are just shown as a flat list. In e.g. IntelliJ it is possible to group pending changes files by their folder.
This is very helpful, because I have multiple files sharing the same filename...

Is there an extension, I can install to add this feature or is it just a config, I did not find, yet?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I see these interface changes in the Insiders Build 1.47:

[image: scm tree/list views]

The `tree/list` option has been removed from the outer `Source Control` header bar and is under the ellipsis (three dots)  now - with additional options if you choose `list`: `path`, `name`, `status`.  As well as the `tree` view you were looking for.

---

As @jabacchetta predicted, this functionality is being added to v1.39 - for scm providers that support it, like git.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_39.md#updated-source-control-view.  And see the link in @jabacchetta's answer.  Tree view in source control.

As usual, you can open/close folders by clikcking on them or left/right arrows.  Demo from the Insider's Build:

[image: source control tree view]

From the Release Notes  :

> **Updated Source Control view**
>
> The Source Control view has been updated to use the latest tree
> widget. You can now toggle between a list and a tree view with the
> Toggle View Mode button on the Source Control title bar.

[image: Toggle SCM View mode button]

> You can change the default view using the scm.defaultViewMode setting,
> which takes the values list or tree.
>
> You also now benefit from the automatic keyboard navigation and
> filtering of the updated tree widget by simply starting to type in the
> view.

[image: scm tree view actions]

> When in tree view mode, which displays folders, the Git extension now
> contributes commands to folders, for example Stage Changes, which will
> be applied to all files within a folder.

Answer (score 2):

Install the [GitLens extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens). Then modify the `gitlens.gitExplorer.files.layout` [setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) to match your preference.

The default `auto` value will automatically change between a "list" and "tree" view, depending on the quantity and location of the files changed. Simply change the setting's value to `tree` if you'd prefer to always have it shown that way.

As for VS Code's built-in SCM functionality, there's a [feature request pending](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14582) for tree-formatting.

Comment: I had GitLens already installed, but didn't know about that feature... thx!